# VB.NET tooltips just stopped working, VS2010, Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tooltip

I've got a complex form where some components are hidden until they are needed. I'd only got a few tooltips set (using the designer rather than doing it myself), but I noticed the other day that they had stopped working. Eventually I'd narrowed it down to some tooltips I'd got set on a tabpage that wasn't visible - If I made the tabpage visible then all the tooltips worked. I've worked round the problem by changing my form_Load code so that the tabpage is only made invisible (and removed from the tab control) right at the end of the form_Load code rather than at the beginning. This solution seems a bit clunky and might stop working if say the form load time changes or something.

Thanks

Kristian

Answer (score 0):

My tooltips stopped working again after I added about 400 tooltips to a form. The tooltips loaded fine initially, but as I kept adding blocks of 100 (I have about 100 tooltip per tab page and may have say 20 tab pages). My fix for this was to create a new tooltip container for every tab page. The tooltip container is still created on the main form, but each tab page will use a different tooltip container.

```
Dim ToolTipPanel As ToolTip    
ToolTipPanel = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(Me.components)
```

I also set the tag property of the tooltip container to keep track of which one was which as I seemed unable to set the name property via code.